# Is the slice of a subcanonical site also subcanonical?

Tags: sheaf-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topology, sites, slice-categories

A subcanonical site is one for which every representable functor is a sheaf.

For a subcanonical site $C$, the fundamental theorem of topos theory says that there is an equivalence $Sh(C/c)\cong Sh(C)/y(c)$, where $y$ is the Yoneda embedding. So the slice of a topos is the topos for a slice.

I'm wondering, can we conclude anything about whether the resulting site for $Sh(C/c)$ is subcanonical?

i.e. for each $f : b \to c$, will $P(g: a \to c) := \{ h : a \to b \mid f \circ h = g  \}$ be a sheaf for the site $C/c$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't this very basic? If $\{a_i \to b\}$ are compatible morphisms in $\mathcal{C}/c$, then these are compatible morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, hence they glue to a unique morphism $a \to b$, and this is a morphism over $c$ since this is the case locally on $a$ and $C$ is subcanonical.

Comment: It might be basic, I assumed it was basic the main references (e.g. NLab) would mention it

Comment: nlab is not a main reference for topos theory. Books are. ;) The statement is contained in Part C, Lemma 2.2.17 in Johnstone's *Sketches of an elephant*. The proof is basically identical to the one in my answer, but phrased in the language of sieves.